# gitpython: How to authenticate as a Github app?

Tags: python, git, github, gitpython

When I do

```py
remote = f"https://{username}:{password}@github.com/user/repo"
git.Repo.clone_from(remote, 'repo')
```

I get to clone the repository with my personal credentials.

But if I try an app credentials

```py
remote = f"https://x-access-token:{token}@github.com/user/repo.git"
git.Repo.clone_from(remote, 'repo')
```

I get

> remote: Invalid username or password. fatal: Authentication failed for
> 'https://github.com/user/repo'

I have installed the app and added it to the repository integrations. It has content permissions to read and write.

I am using the client secret as the token.

Comment: I saw on Github documentation (https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/authenticating-with-github-apps) that you need to generate something called `installation access tokens`, but I found that too complicated and I don't know how to do that in Python. I was wondering if the `gitpython` library makes it easier.

Comment: I tried the solution in https://github.com/swinton/pygithub-playground/blob/main/demo.py but got `ValueError: Could not deserialize key data`.

Comment: this is a different package not gitpython - its from pygithub